# Navigation Bar problems

Tags: css, wordpress, nav

I have several problems that I have been unable to resolve:

How do I center the whole menu? Right now, the only way I’ve been able to do that is through this code:

```
.not-fixed #site-title, .not-fixed #navigation {
   margin: 0px auto;
   max-width: 900px;
   float: none;
 }
```

However, for some reason, there is a very ugly top padding now on any page that isn’t white (see homepage). Therefore, how do I center this menu to avoid this problem? please see the result of that in this screenshot: https://flic.kr/p/o8eMB5

Next, as you will note: there is a TOP vertical align on the text content in this menu. We would like it to be a center vertical align. Can you please show us how to do this?

Screenshot: https://flic.kr/p/o8eMB5

Lastly, if you will look at the edges of the menu on the home page, you’ll see that they don’t look right. There still seems to be a bit of the old menu there. How do we get rid of that to make the edges look clean?

Website: visualicreative.com

Comment: > I have several problems... I suggest you ask each question in a separate post

Comment: Something I noticed is fairly heavy usage of `!important` in the CSS. This doesn't contribute directly to the problems you're having right now, but it will make maintaining and expanding the CSS problematic. I'd really suggest avoiding using it unless absolutely necessary, and eliminating as many instances of it as you can in your existing CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this CSS to your CSS file and you should be good.

This CSS will vertically center the nav items:

```
#mega_main_menu > .menu_holder > .menu_inner > ul > li > .item_link > .link_content {
  padding: 10px 0 !important;
}
```

This will take out the white background on the NAV:

```
.not-fixed #navigation {
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

As to your last question, I am not sure what you are referring to as "There still seems to be a bit of the old menu there"

Hope that helps, let me know if I can help out in any other way.

Comment: you fixed my problem!! Oh, thank you so much; you're a wonderful person!!

Comment: I'm having a little trouble with the top padding of this menu now Amir. I'd like it to be closer to the top of the browser but it appears like the navbar is getting in the way. this is the code i'm using. The top-padding that i've put in there is not functional. Hopefully you can help!
    
.not-fixed #site-title, .not-fixed #navigation {
max-width: 900px;
max-height: 30px !important;
padding-top: 10px !important;
float: none;
margin: auto;
}